# How do I pause/save Game1 then run another class over/instead of it?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm using XNA 3.0 and C# 2008 now in case that makes a difference. Okay so What I'm trying to do is run class 'Game1', then on collision stop 'Game1' and switch over to class 'B'. Then I need class 'B' to return to 'Game1' without resetting 'Game1'. (Both classes are user interactive) Sorry about the lack of specific I'm new and really not grasping this concept.

Comment: Please include some code to illustrate your situation. Try not to copy&paste your whole code, but extract the representative bits and pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Game1` class is always running, if you want to switch from a class to another I think you have to create other two classes, or create two instances of the same (all managed by `Game1`) and do the switch on them.